# iOS App shows black screen after succesful install on device using Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying to install an app using Xcode 12.5 on my personal device which is an iPhone 7 plus running iOS 15 underneath.

I got it to work after much hassle by adding iOS 15 device support files, but, after the app installs and launches itself, I get a black screen for like a minute or two and then the app works fine.

However, if I debug it takes approximately 30-40 seconds from jumping to one breakpoint to another and it consumes a lot of time.

I have tried scouring for a lot of information on this but no luck. Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: So you've somehow hacked Xcode to do an unsupported thing and then you're complaining that it doesn't work very well?

Comment: @matt the question does not mention a hacked XCode application

Comment: @ElectricDragon I think it does.

Comment: It's not a hacked Xcode guys. I just added device support files for iOS 15 in Xcode 12.5 so I could deploy on my device. I followed a tutorial from SO itself to do so. How does it count  as a "hacked Xcode". ? @matt

Answer (score -2):

You probably disabled your Splash screen that is why black screen appears.
Go in your LaunchScreen.storyboard file, there you will find a Screen Controller. Make it story board entry point and give it a background color of your choice.

Comment: And how does that explain "However, if i debug it takes approximately 30-40 seconds from jumping to one breakpoint to another and it consumes a lot of time"?

Comment: Go to Edit Scheme in Xcode(Click on Target name where device is shown).
See under the Launch set it to automatically.

Comment: @GhulamMustafa It's already set to "launch automatically". Doesn't help.